# Getting "No query executer factory registered for the "WebServiceQuery" language" error

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have this project I am working on. It entails printing a report using jasper. I did the design using Jasper Studio and everything works fine. I can export the report into any format. My problem now is that I want to do this printing from withing Java.

The data to be printed comes from a web service. This works in Jasper studio. When I follow all the tutorials online that explains how it is done, I get the `No query executer factory registered for the "WebServiceQuery" language.` error

This is my lines of code that is suppose to do the job.

```
       JasperReport jasperReport =  JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\Me\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\posinvoice2.jrxml") ;

        // Parameters for report
        HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        parameters.put("CONNECTION_ID", connectionId);
        parameters.put("VISIT_ID" , visitId);

        // DataSource
        // This is simple example, no database.
        // then using empty datasource.
        JRDataSource dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource() ;

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, dataSource);

        // Make sure the output directory exists.
        File outDir = new File("C:/JaspersReports");
        outDir.mkdirs();

        // Export to PDF.
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                "C:/JaspersReports/InvoiceReport.pdf");
```

I read in some documentation that we had to set the property, but all that I see focuses on plsql. Please can someone help me sort out this error?

Comment: Unless you're actually modifying the JRXML file dynamically, there's no need to compile the JRXML file each time. Load the compiled .jasper file, instead.

Comment: It is not the culprit. Create a minimal working example that shows the problem. The above code is insufficient to reproduce the issue you're having.